# Sentry not initializing in Vue 3 custom components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component, sentry

I'm getting the following warning when trying to connect sentry in my vue 3 custom web components

> [@sentry/vue]: Misconfigured SDK. Vue specific errors will not be captured. Update your `Sentry.init` call with an appropriate config option: `app` (Application Instance - Vue 3) or `Vue` (Vue Constructor - Vue 2)

This is my applications entry point

```
// Custom Elements 
export function registerComponent1() {
  customElements.define('name1', defineCustomElement(Component1));
}
export function registerComponent2() {
  customElements.define('name2', defineCustomElement(Component2));
}
export function registerComponent3() {
  customElements.define('name3', defineCustomElement(Component3));
}


export const defineCustomElement = (component) => {
  
  return VueDefineCustomElement({
    setup() {
      const inst = getCurrentInstance();

      Sentry.init({
        app: inst.appContext.app,
        dsn: '...'
        integrations: [Sentry.browserTracingIntegration()],
        // Performance Monitoring
        tracesSampleRate: 1.0, //  Capture 100% of the transactions
      });

      return () => h(component);
    },
  });
};
```

I tested the connect by created a button like such  and it seems to be working

```
function sendSentryData() {
  Sentry.captureMessage('Button clicked');
}

 <button @click="sendSentryData">Click me</button>
```

So what's causing this issue, like I want to track when networks requests fail, vue or non-vue specific issues. Also will implementing it like such initialize Sentry three times?

passed application instance to Sentry.init by

```
getCurrentInstance().appContext.app;
```

Comment: did you `Update your Sentry.init call with an appropriate config option`?

Comment: @JaromandaX yess you can see in the question, I added all the required configs

Comment: From what I can see you are not following the Sentry docs to the tee: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/vue/#vue-3

I recommend putting your `Sentry.init()` call in the global scope and passing your Vue app instance.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow missed that